# How can I get a listview like the following Apple Music playlist overview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, listview, apple-music

I am searching for a Listview in Swift that looks like the following:

Wanted ListView:-

[image]

I want a ListVIew that has a picture in the background and a text over the picture. And when I click at that picture, I want to go to the next site.

And how I get these Header?

Header Example:-

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Implement the [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) with `customTableCell`. On your customTableCell class draw the custom design as shown in your requirement image. Implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method to goto the next site.

Comment: in the customTableCell I set the background with the image and set a text over the image?

Comment: Set a background image. Set a left aligned label. Set the `accessoryType` of cell to `UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator`.

Comment: Okay thanks, I edited  the question, can you tell me how I get the Header?

Comment: as @pkc456 says, custom cell is the only way to get your desired design, you can add a UIImageView as background and a label as title and from storyboard or by programmatically add UITableViewCellAccessoryType to DisclosureIndicator.

Comment: Is your comment for the header or the list?

Comment: sorry when I was typing your question changed :P

Comment: Note:- Please try not to post image as link. Custom header:- Set the translucent navigation bar. Set the [custom image](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-section-header-to-a-table-view) in your headerview.

Comment: Ok, Let me post all the above details in answer.

Comment: you can have it by using `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Implement the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) with customTableCell.
- On your customTableCell class draw the custom design as shown in your requirement image. (Set a background image. Set a left aligned label.)
- Implement the [didSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) delegate method to goto the next site.
- Set the accessoryType of cell to [`UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcellaccessorytype/1623225-disclosureindicator)
- Custom header:- Set the `translucent` navigation bar. Set the custom image in your headerview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) to achieve your requirements mentioned in question. You can use custom cell and can add `UIImageview` and `UILabel` on it to show image and title. Second thing you can implement `tableHeaderView` which can fullfill your need of header. `Tableview` is memory efficient with great performance. So, in your case `UITableView` is the right choice.